# Tableau desktop 2021.02 oracle server 19c frequent disconnection - error code dacbe23f

Tags: oracle, tableau-desktop

I recently started using tableau. I followed below step to connect with oracle.
I placed ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar into C:\Program Files\Tableau\Drivers directory, java 8 installed and JAVA_HOME is set.

Below is the jdbc jar i am using

```
<dependency> 
 <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId> 
 <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId> 
 <version>19.10.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Then I am able to connect to oracle database, but during data filtering I am getting disconnection very frequently, almost unusable and this error code "dacbe23f"
Also in log below error

> "user":"-","k":"msg","v":"Cannot load library from preferred location, "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 2021.2\bin\oci.dll", since it doesn't exist.","ctx":{"client-procid":..............."
>
> Load library failed: Cannot load library oci: The specified module
> could not be found

After checking on tableau support, I found [this post](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/Issue/error-an-error-occurred-while-communicating-with-the-data-source-connecting-to-oracle?_ga=2.226746525.1863768893.1638290857-663656002.1628695681). Please read this question it is same with my situation, however this post is post suggesting the use of oracle client, I am not using oracle client

I found oracle client in [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html)

I am thinking  of setting oracle home in env variable and copy the dll files to oracle_home directory as mentioned in env variable.
Can anyone please suggest do I really need to install oracle client or specifying the ORACLE_HOME should be enough.

Also I am little confused why tableau is looking for oracle client ddl where as it is using jdbc jar for connection and able to connect.

Comment: adding ORACLE_HOME helped me a lot now having less connection drop still not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Oracle JDBC driver instead of JDBC-OCI driver with Tableau.
The JDBC OCI driver use requires you to set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>  this one i am using what you suggest to use ?